# Quitar una extensión en C

Tags: c

tengo que quitar la extensión de un fichero (.txt). He intentado recorrer el array de derecha a izquierda pero no sé como hacerlo. Ya que no se pueden eliminar todos los puntos, t ni x. Por ejemplo, si tenemos un fichero que se llama: datostexto.txt, quiero que se quede "datostexto" no "daoseo".
Gracias de antemano.

```
void quitar(char *f){
        char exten[4] = ".txt";
        char f1_aux[25];
        int x = 0;
        int i;

        for(i = strlen(f1); i >= 0; i--){

            if (f1[i] != exten[i]){

                f1_aux[x] = f1[i];
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado de código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución:

```
/**
 * Quita extensión al final de un nombre de archivo.
 * 
 * @param nombre El nombre de archivo a examinar.
 * @param extension La extensión a buscar.
 */
void quitar(char *nombre, char* extension) {
    int desplazamiento = strlen(nombre) - strlen(extension);
    char *start = nombre + desplazamiento;
    
    if (strcmp(start, extension) == 0) {
        *start = 0;
    }
}
```

La función `strcmp` está comparando los últimos caracteres de `nombre` contra `extension` la extensión. La función `strcmp` retorna 0 si ambas cadenas son iguales. En tal caso, se corta la cadena `nombre` poniendo un cero en donde comienza la extensión.

**Demo**

```
int main() {
    char nombre[] = "nombre_archivo.txt";
    char nombre2[] = "nombre.text";
    char nombre3[] = "nombre.tx";
    char nombre4[] = "nombre.txt2";

    char extension[] = ".txt";

    quitar(nombre, extension);
    printf("%s\n", nombre);
    quitar(nombre2, extension);
    printf("%s\n", nombre2);
    quitar(nombre3, extension);
    printf("%s\n", nombre3);
    quitar(nombre4, extension);
    printf("%s\n", nombre4);
}
```

produce

```
nombre_archivo
nombre.text
nombre.tx
nombre.txt2
```